# Create Android splash screen using SVG animation

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to insert the splash screen to my Android project.

I found a few tutorials for creating a splash screen with a background color and a static png image, but I want to use my svg animation as splash screen. I thought I could follow a tutorial for static image and just replace the png image with the svg animation, but it didn't work. Here's what I have so far:

On `SplashActivity.cs`:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "SplashActivity", Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
            startupWork.Start();
        }

        async void SimulateStartup()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
    }
```

On `MainActivity.cs`:

```cs
// I only changed the MainLauncher property to false
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        ...
    }
```

On `styles.xml` (in the Xamarin.Android project):

```xml
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/desenhando5s</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#004632</item>
  </style>
```

When I run the application, it only shows a black screen as splash screen and then shows my login page as always.
Can anybody tell me what I have to do to set my animation as the splash screen?

(FYI: in case anyone wants to know, I created the animation using [SVGator](https://www.svgator.com/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FFImageLoading` to load your svg image in your `SplashActivity` instead of set it in `styles.xml`.

Splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout5);

        var filePath = "check";
        var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(filePath).WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(64, 0, true)).Into(imageView);
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
```

**Updated:**

Please check the screenshot. The .svg image is in the `drawable` folder.  The layout5 is the splash screen in the layout folder.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I keep getting the error `Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'File res/drawable/desenhando5s.svg from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f080062'` when it reaches the `SetContentView` line. My file could not be found on Resource.Layout, so I changed it to Resource.Drawable

Comment: I manually created a folder named "layout" inside my Resources folder, and added the svg file to this folder, but when I run the app I get the exception `Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'File res/layout/desenhando5s.svg from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0c0021'` when it reaches the `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.desenhando5s);` line

Comment: You could check my update. Put the `desenhando5s.svg` in drawable folder. `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.YourLayoutName)` is used to load the splash screen.